# How to prevent an activity from being the root activity of a task

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to prevent an activity from becoming the root activity of a task? Can we mark it in the Manifest File?

**UPDATE:**

I have marked my activity's launch mode as `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to avoid multiple instances. What could be possible work-around in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just define that activity in android manifest file for eg.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

Without giving any other attributes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **do not** need to do anything extra to prevent an activity to be the root activity. You just need to avoid adding following attributes while defining your activity in  AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```